# SQLITE3 insertion in xcode4

Tags: ios5, xcode4, sqlite

I'm using `SQLITE3` for database operation in iPhone application.

I've 2 table in database and I want to insert into 2 tables in different situation.

My problem is for first time the insertion operation works fine. If I try to insert into another table the value's get insert into last inserted table.

My code for Table1 is :

```
-(void)addToTable1

{

    if(addStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "insert into Table(T1_Name) Values(?)";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlCurrency, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [T1_Name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    else
        rowID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

    sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Code for Table2 is :

```
-(void)addToTable2
{
    if(addStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "insert into Table2(T2_Name) Values(?)";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlWeight, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [T2_Name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    else
        rowID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

    sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
    sqlite3_close(database);

}
```

I'm not getting any clue why its happening.

Answer (score 1):

You must reset `addStmt` to `nil` after you have freed it, otherwise the `if(addStmt == nil)` check will prevent the new statement from being used.

Furthermore, you must use [`sqlite3_finalize`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html), not [`sqlite3_reset`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/reset.html), before closing the database.

Comment: +1 Better still keep the statement handle local to the method.

Comment: I used sqlite3_finalize in AppDelegate.m which will immediately executes after insertion.

Comment: I got the problem it was because of rowID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database); so used new file to insert to table2 is that rite way? or is there any other simpler way?